# What list can the Orange Prism's extra cantrip be chosen from?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

A [cracked orange prism (ioun stone)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone) grants an additional cantrip.

However, the text does not specify from which list you can add it.

Does it have to be your class list, even if not specified, or can it be another list? If (as it seems might be the case) the user doesn't get to choose the cantrip, what happens if the cantrip isn't in their class list — do they get it anwyay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The spell is already chosen

The *user* of a cracked orange prism Ioun stone doesn't get to choose. When you ask if it has to be from “your class list”, it sounds like you're thinking that a character who finds the stone gets to choose, but [that is not the case](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone):

> Wearer adds one cantrip or orison (**determined when the stone is created**) to his list of spells known or spells prepared.

Like a wand or a scroll, a cracked orange prism already has the cantrip or orison it grants set when it is created. Just like when finding a wand you actually find a *wand of fireballs* or *wand of cure light wounds*, when you find a cracked orange prism Ioun stone you are actually finding one for a specific spell, such as a *cracked orange prism Ioun stone of [prestidigitation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation)* or a *cracked orange prism Ioun stone of [know direction](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/k/know-direction)*.

There doesn't appear to be a class-based condition on adding the cantrip or orison to your list of spells known/prepared — the magic item itself just adds it, regardless, and specific beats general. So yes, you would get it regardless. For example, a druid using a *cracked orange prism Ioun stone of prestidigitation* would have *prestidigitation* as one of their orison choices.

Comment: Ok, then I'll rephrase it as "what if the chosen cantrip is not in my class list? Do I get it anyway?"

Comment: @Matteo That sounds like a decent amendment to your question.

Comment: Done :) the new version still stands though ...

Comment: Paragraph on that added!

Comment: That would be my interpretation too ... which leads to another question, which I'll post right away!