# How is the Orange Prism's extra cantrip determined?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

According to the answer which emerged on my [previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90836/what-list-can-the-orange-prisms-extra-cantrip-be-chosen-from), it would seem that the cantrip granted by a [cracked Orange Prism Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone) is not chosen by the user but

> [...] determined when the stone is created [...]

So my question is, how is it "determined"? Randomly? By its creator? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: Is the question about when you create one yourself, how you pick the cantrip?

Comment: No, not really, rather about when you buy it or find it

Comment: In the story, it is determined by whomever created it. In the game, it is decided by the GM when he decides to include it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are buying the stone, then you buy the stone with the cantrip you want from the magic shop.  If you find it in random loot then it comes with a spell already on it determined by the GM.